# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when adding a new API in wso2am

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I downloaded wso2am-1.9.0.zip to my MacBook and expanded it. I did not change any of the config or anything else. I started it up with bin/wso2server.sh, as documented. It seemed to start up successfully. I was able to login to the API Publisher with admin/admin, as documented. When I tried to add a simple new API (just one endpoint) I got the following stacktrace:

```
[2015-07-22 12:47:06,801] ERROR - add:jag org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 (/publisher/modules/api/add.jag#99)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3._c_anonymous_5(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag:99)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3.call(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_30(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:98)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag:100)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag:5)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:541)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.addAPI(ApiMgtDAO.java:6379)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.addAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:395)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.addAPI(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:46)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.saveAPI(APIProviderHostObject.java:900)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_createAPI(APIProviderHostObject.java:798)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    ... 58 more
```

Comment: what is the context value you used? similar issue is reported in this jira  https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-3977.

Comment: What was the context you have given when creating the api?

Comment: @Ushani I used /{version}

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs when you give context as /{version}. This issue [1] is already identified and in open state and will be fixed in up coming releases. As a work around you can provide some other value as well to your context and create the api. E.g., test/{version} or /{version}/test or test/{version}/somestring

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-3977